# CSS: 3 divs - Resizing 2 outer divs automatically based on width of inner div/text

Tags: css, html, overflow, css-float

My problem is best outlined with this schematic/image which outlines how I want it to look:

[image: http://i51.tinypic.com/28thuh0.jpg]
!

I have a background image and 2 divs for text over the top of it (headline, and intro-text). I also have 2 divs on either side of the headline - these are for the white horizontal stripes.

My issue is that the headline is changeable in a CMS, and I want the horizontal white stripes to automatically fill up the space to the left and to the right of it, regardless of the headline's width.

I can't figure out how to make those 2 horizontal white stripes resize automatically.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="masthead">
<div id="headline-container">   
    <div id="left-stripe">&nbsp;</div><div id="headline">{headline}</div><div id="right-stripe">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="clear-both">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="intro-text">{intro_text}</div>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS - ignore the widths specified for the left-stripe and right-stripe - they're just placeholders:

```
#masthead {
    height: 260px;
}

div#headline-container {
    width:960px;
    padding:none;
}
div#left-stripe{
    float: left;
    background-color:#fff;
    height: 3px;
    width:500px;
    display: inline;
}
div#right-stripe{
    float: right;
    background-color:#fff;
    height: 3px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline;
}
div#headline {
    text-align:right;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 200%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;    
}
div#intro-text {
    text-align: left;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Ideas? Please let me know if I can provide more detail.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  For stuff like this it's good to find a `live` example and not just a screen

Comment: Maybe a rewording of my actual question then: How do I make the 2 white stripes fill up any remaining space to the left and the right of the headline div, regardless of the headline text's width (which will change).

Comment: (change the actual question) =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit too busy to actually test this, but this might give you some direction.  i'm not sure the exact effect you're trying to achieve (see comment about finding a live demo someone made).

Regardless, this kind of fluid layout is a bit difficult to achieve reliably with straight CSS.  To make it easier I would suggest making the right-stripe a static width.

This CSS solution MIGHT work... no promises.

### markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="headline-container">
   <div class="left-stripe"></div>
   <div class="headline">Headline goes here</div>
   <div class="right-stripe></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
//static width for right stripe
.right-stripe { width: 20px; }
.headline { width: auto; }
.left-stripe { width: auto; }
```

Using javascript would make it really easy though... here's how i would do it with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Again, I would make the right-stripe a static width to achieve this effect.

### (same markup...)

..

### js

```
var totalWidth = $("#container").width();
var leftWidth = totalWidth - ($("headline").width() + $("right-stripe").width());
$("left-stripe").width(leftWidth);
```

Comment: Tried the CSS-only one, no go. I started that way. I've decided to use the jQuery method after-all. I think it's the simplest and allows me to move on, amen!

Comment: yea... sometimes css just can't get the job done.  Although, with CSS 3/html5 i think it could be done if you wanted to put the time... but it'd be a wasteland in x-browser-land

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** CSS only fluid solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/XnvYw/1/

it uses the same background image twice, on `#masthead` and on `#headline-container`.  except ton headline container the background is offset to match its left position relative to its parent element.  then we only need one `div.line` behind it, which gets covered by the background image under the headline and copy, giving the illusion of a seamless image.

<strike>do you mean like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/XnvYw/</strike>

Comment: I believe he is looking for a way to do this "fluidly"

Comment: Indeed, "fluidly" is the key.

Comment: @Sebastian That doesn't quite do what I need. If you change the headline to something longer or shorter, you have problems. See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/XnvYw/8/

Comment: Of course, if oyu have a headline that goes over the edge of the parent container, and its all oneword ussing camelcase, and it stretches the line, it will look weird, but if you simply put a space in your headline, it will fold under and work.

Comment: Right, my bad, I should've mentioned, I don't want it to go to another line, it should just stretch out. I think the best/easiest way is with jQuery.

Comment: @Kook. I believe this solution is more elegant as it doesn't require js, and if you play wih the values you can do a lot.  but you can always take the js route too.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that. I may play if I have some down time. It's just now coming to a point where I shouldn't waste any more time on this piece of the project and need to move on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dynamically, with jQuery, for example. You take the full width of the 3 div's, drop the size of the inner div and assign dynamically the widths of the 2 outer div's in which the bar should repeat horizontally.

Basically, you will need:
`$("#whole-div").width() - $("#inner-div").width()` for the outer div's total width. Then, depending on your positioning of the inner-div, you assign values for the outer div's.
For example: whole div has 1000px, inner div has 200px and inner div is positioned 600px left. You will then assign 600px to the left div (`$("#whole-div").width() - $("#inner-div").css('left')`) and 200px for the right div (`$("#whole-div").width() - $("#inner-div").css('left') - $("#inner-div").width()`). Of course, you will then set a `background-repeat` property on the outer div so that the image repeats.

Hope that helps!